# Xserver shows just the icons on the second screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, xserver, multiple-users

i would like to have two different Xserver sessions, because i want to use the same machine from two differet computer by VNC. I mean we are two different person that need to work in the same server, with VNC, at the same time. So, to do that, i tried opening a second Xserver session (in the server machine), to connect each user on a different session. To do that, i typed CTRL + ALT + F1 and then the command `startx -- :1`. Then if i try typing CTRL + ALT + F1 to switch the screen it appears another desktop which shows just the icons on it. I mean it is impossible to do anything on the second screen. Am i missing anything ?